# Check input types and skip input 'password' field while click SAVE

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

I have a form - Only a part of it is attached next.

I have a script that change the input PASSWORD type to TEXT if I like to.
My problem is, If I click 'Update' while the input 'Password_field' input type is 'PASSWORD', The form send the information from all fields.

What I want is thet while the 'Password_field' input type is 'PASSWORD' the form will not send the information from the 'Password_field' input - Skip it..
Only if the 'Password_field' input type is 'TEXT' I want to save the data from this spacific field.

Basically, I want the form to save the info from ALL FIELDS in any case, but will skip the 'Password_field' input if his type is 'PASSWORD'.

What is the easiest way to do it? and How? :)

Any suggestions?

Tx

```
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT DBTABLE, Full_Name, Phone, Password FROM Names WHERE id='" . $id . "'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    $resultArr = array();
    $i = 0;
    if (isset($result->num_rows) && $result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        if ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $Full_Name = $row["Full_Name"];
            $Phone = $row["Phone"];
            $Password = $row["Password"];        
        }
    }
}
?>

<form action="" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="id"/>
Full_Name
<input  style="margin-top:10px; margin-bottom:15px;" id="Full_Name" type="text" name="Full_Name" value="Full_Name"/>

Phone
<input  style="margin-top:10px; margin-bottom:15px;" id="Phone" type="text" name="Phone" value="Phone"/>
-- > Password_field 
<input  style="margin-top:10px; margin-bottom:15px;" id="Password_field" type="password" name="Password_field" value="***"/> <---

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update" style="margin-left: 4px; font-size: 18px;"/>     
 </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can disable your password field before submitting. Check if input type is password then disable it and submit the form. Disbaled fields will not be submitted.

Comment: Thank you for reply! 
I added disabled="disabled" to the field.
I have a line on the <script> that change the input:
resultInput.attr('type', 'text').val('Loading...');

What line shuold I add to the <script> to remove the disabled="disabled" from the input?

Thanks

Comment: use input.attr('disabled', false);